# Find a word in file and base on it, look up/above to find another (bash/shell)

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file like below

```
Name: Country name
Line1
Line2 In this line is the word I want to find 
Line3
Line4
......
LineN
Name: Country name
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4 In this line is the word I want to find
......
LineN
More sections like above....
```

Number of lines is variable in each section... I want to find a word (I can do it using grep) in any of the lines but after that, I need to go up and get the "Name: Country name" too, I have try to look for solutions but haven't had luck, any advise?

I have only tried grep and grep -AN or -BN but since number of lines variable and the match can be in any line, it's not easy to find the country name

Comment: In general, you can't go backwards with the shell's IO primitives, but you _can_ keep the previous line in memory as you read, so when you see the thing you're looking for you check what's in the "what was the last line?" variable. Or, in this case, you'd look for the `Name:` lines, store whatever you find in them in `last_name`, and then when you see your word you look at the `last_name` variable. Awk is a better tool for grep for this, if your file is too large for it to be efficient to just do in bash itself with no external tools at all (as with a `while read` loop).

Answer (score 4):

Use `awk`. When it sees a `Name:` line it saves it in a variable, when it sees the line you want to match it prints the variable.

```
awk '/^Name:/ {country = $0; next}
     /word-to-find/ {print country}' file.txt
```